# How to run ROS2 binaries without source folder

Tags: ros2, colcon

I am new to ROS. I try to build [demo_nodes_cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/rolling/demo_nodes_cpp) example. I use `colcon build`, `source install/setup.bash` to setup and `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker` to run. All works fine.

Now I want to copy all the binary files into another machine and run it. Then I find many built files use absolute symlink that link to my host PC. How can I just use the built files without depending on my building host environemnt?

Comment: Did you try to copy the files to the ROS2 system space? For example, `rsync -av ROSWS/install/YOURPACKAGE/* /opt/ros/humble/` should work for ROS2 humble in Ubuntu 22.04. It's not a clean way to install software, but it should work as a first start.